# Web Part Error: Access Denied sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, access

I have created a document library and given only specific users access. All other users see the Web Part Error: Access Denied. We don't want them to see the web part or the error. I thought that if they didn't have access, they just wouldn't see the web part.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** feature under site collection features:

[image]

After that, the document library with restricted access is displayed as an empty library for users without permission on the page, and the error disappears：

[image]