# Getting "Web Part Error: Access denied" message on SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, access-denied

I have the same **Web Part Error: Access denied** error as in the question below, from Linda Baldwin, but in my case I am using SPS2016. My need is the same, as well: I do not want the error message to appear when an user without permissions to that web part access the site.

[Web Part Error: Access Denied sharepoint 365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/298341/71688)

The answer proposed for that question, from Julie_MSFT does not seem to work for me. The **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** is already deactivated in my site collection.

Is there something else I could try to get rid of the error messages?
Thank you very much in advance.

[image: SPSerror]